# How upload a file using selenium to a shockwave object.?

Tags: python, selenium, python-2.7

I am unable to upload few text file using a python script with selenium web driver.

Tried

```
driver.find_element_by_id("file_uploadUploader").send_keys("c:\file.txt")
```

There is no submit button on the screen.

Application:

The interface consist of one button which opens up into a window in which we select the file and then press save(cancel is the other option) which upload the file.
From HTML code I read that it is a  object of type="application/x-shockwave-flash"
id="file_uploadUploader" controlled by data="/media/uploadify/uploadify.swf

```
    #<param value="high" name="quality">
    #<param value="opaque" name="wmode">
    #<param value="sameDomain" name="allowScriptAccess">
    #<param value="uploadifyID=file_upload..............>
```

How upload a file using selenium to a shockwave object in python ??

Comment: I'm afraid you are stuck (and anyone please correct me if I  am wrong) as you wouldn't be able to locate the shockwave object with Selenium..You need a more advanced paid tool in order to work with flash content and coordinates..